# DatabaseGeneratedOption: Identity vs. Computed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to understand the (functional) difference between the two `DatabaseGeneratedOption`'s in Entity Framework (code first):

- `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`
- `DatebaseGeneratedOption.Computed`

I have read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx), but I do not understand the functional difference between the two.

The option **Identity** is described as *The database generates a value when a row is inserted*. But I cannot update the value later if I try I get an exception saying that I cannot modify a column with Identity pattern.

The option **Computed**  is described as *The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated*. However, this is just what you tell Entity Framework, so far I have not been able to achieve this, without SQL triggers. If I try to update the value, nothing happens (Entity Framework refuses to overwrite the existing value).

So what I am left with, is two functionally identical options. I can have a default value in my SQL table, which will be applied on the insert. And I cannot update this value afterward (using Entity Framework). So where in lies the difference in how they should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) contains a value that is computed (hence the name) when the record is requested.

A computed column can be composed of other column values, constants and function return values.

You could for example create a computed column for an invoice expiry date:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
    InvoiceDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ExpiryDate AS DATEADD(DAY, 30, InvoiceDate)
)
```

Now if you mark this column as computed in Entity Framework, it will refuse any updates to that column, because it'll know the database won't support that.

So the documentation for that attribute is incorrect or incomplete.

A column marked as Identity will use the database-specific syntax to generate a primary key for the given table when inserting a record, being `IDENTITY()` in MSSQL and `AUTO_INCREMENT` for MySQL. A computed column will simply be marked as read-only, and you'll have to provide your own implementation (either in the database or in your migration file) to specify the computation (see [How to add computed column using migrations in code first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529883/how-to-add-computed-column-using-migrations-in-code-first)).

Comment: But if I marked the column as `.Identity` wouldn't it have the exact same result (although semantically incorrect)? From what I can tell, both attributes simply renders the column as read only?

Comment: But what if I do not use Entity Framework to add columns (I am using an existing database)? In that case, will they not have the exact same function?

Comment: Well in that case - still yes and no. You can't specify multiple Identity columns on an entity, for example.

Comment: "*A column marked as Identity will use the database-specific syntax to generate a primary key*": According to [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions](https://dev.to/peledzohar/sql-server-s-identity-column-misconceptions-19lj) nothing guarantees uniqueness of an identity column. "*The identity property on a column does not guarantee Uniqueness of the value. Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index*". Or maybe this is only true when creating the table with EF, EF taking care of that.

Comment: @mins I fail to see the point of that linked blog. Yes, there are a lot of technical caveats, but a column marked as UNIQUE, INT, NOT NULL, IDENTITY is good enough. And you do so by naming it `Id` or `$EntityNameId` and marking it as `[Key]` and `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, so that  is enough.