# How can I make a migration with a new field that will be dynamically populated, for example by multiplying two other already existing fields in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have entity **ProductItem** and the database is already updated by migration with this template:

```
public class ProductItem
    {
        public ProductItem()
        {
            Price = 0;
            Discount = 0;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        public int Discount { get; set; }
    }
```

My database is already populated with some entities.
I would like to add one more field **TotalPrice**:

```
public class ProductItem
    {
        public ProductItem()
        {
            Price = 0;
            Discount = 0;
            TotalPrice = 0;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        public int Discount { get; set; }

        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

When adding a field **TotalPrice** , it will be filled with default values, but I need it to be filled using a simple formula  Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01)  for each field.

Here is my code for new migration with field TotalPrice:

```
    public partial class _addedTotalPrice : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<double>(
                name: "TotalPrice",
                table: "ProductItems",
                type: "float",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValueSql: "ROUND(Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01),0)");

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: "96ba8f64-053a-4574-a0bb-b73ecc88c761",
                column: "ConcurrencyStamp",
                value: "431db11e-8531-48bc-9483-5b13c0759d4e");

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: "4c6e757b-ecb2-40a8-94fe-a2d3ecca28ca",
                columns: new[] { "ConcurrencyStamp", "PasswordHash" },
                values: new object[] { "390090d0-226e-43f6-af69-c3a139d602c0", "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEEcQUTyWcGF4TKR/qdtnDij7UjPt9NBtkwYw8WJX6CcVKnGBM8BuOj+YJVhYdgrA7A==" });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "TotalPrice",
                table: "ProductItems");

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: "96ba8f64-053a-4574-a0bb-b73ecc88c761",
                column: "ConcurrencyStamp",
                value: "734fc36f-7481-4782-942f-61ec56112815");

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: "4c6e757b-ecb2-40a8-94fe-a2d3ecca28ca",
                columns: new[] { "ConcurrencyStamp", "PasswordHash" },
                values: new object[] { "3209c2fd-5fc0-46a9-9689-b73b3b7617af", "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEMLDk9vuX+uj98bjcAPnzRvfHw37gfJttkgeQ+vkpXzoIbOdf0tyNcJ38/uzuNCyhA==" });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it with **defaultValueSql** but it doesn't work:

```
defaultValueSql: "ROUND(Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01),0)");
```

and

```
defaultValueSql: "SELECT ROUND(Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01),0) FROM dbo.ProductItems");
```

How can this be solved?
Here is Terminal:

```
PM> dotnet ef database update 20210205151510__addedTotalPrice
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.1' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.2'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER TABLE [ProductItems] ADD [TotalPrice] float NOT NULL DEFAULT (ROUND(Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01),0));
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [ProductItems] ADD [TotalPrice] float NOT NULL DEFAULT (ROUND(Price*(1 - Discount * 0.01),0));
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): РРјСЏ "Price" РЅРµ СЂР°Р·СЂРµС€РµРЅРѕ РІ РґР°РЅРЅРѕРј РєРѕРЅС‚РµРєСЃС‚Рµ. Р”РѕРїСѓСЃС‚РёРјС‹РјРё РІС‹СЂР°Р¶РµРЅРёСЏРјРё СЏРІР»СЏСЋС‚СЃСЏ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚С‹, РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ РІС‹СЂР°Р¶РµРЅРёСЏ Рё (РІ РЅРµРєРѕС‚РѕСЂС‹С… РєРѕРЅС‚РµРєСЃС‚Р°С…) РїРµСЂРµРјРµРЅРЅС‹Рµ. РРјРµРЅР° СЃС‚РѕР»Р±С†РѕРІ РЅРµ СЂР°Р·СЂРµС€РµРЅС‹.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:9d817364-061a-4ade-b122-b50ca873140f
Error Number:128,State:1,Class:15
РРјСЏ "Price" РЅРµ СЂР°Р·СЂРµС€РµРЅРѕ РІ РґР°РЅРЅРѕРј РєРѕРЅС‚РµРєСЃС‚Рµ. Р”РѕРїСѓСЃС‚РёРјС‹РјРё РІС‹СЂР°Р¶РµРЅРёСЏРјРё СЏРІР»СЏСЋС‚СЃСЏ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚С‹, РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚РЅС‹Рµ РІС‹СЂР°Р¶РµРЅРёСЏ Рё (РІ РЅРµРєРѕС‚РѕСЂС‹С… РєРѕРЅС‚РµРєСЃС‚Р°С…) РїРµСЂРµРјРµРЅРЅС‹Рµ. РРјРµРЅР° СЃС‚РѕР»Р±С†РѕРІ РЅРµ СЂР°Р·СЂРµС€РµРЅС‹.
PM>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could use procedure to fix the problem.

Comment: I understand that this can be done after migration, but I would like to understand if there is a similar functionality in migrations.

Comment: If i were u, I would calculate it inside code, for real, for example when u are adding this object to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TotalPrice column should be computed column. Here is the link that will point you how to do this:

[How to add computed column using migrations in code first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529883/how-to-add-computed-column-using-migrations-in-code-first)

Also, table columns are not allowed in `defaultValueSql` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL script which updates the value of all existing entries in your database.

e.g. assume you create a folder named 'Sql' next to your migrations folder with a script 'UpdateTotalPrice.sql', you can execute it from your migration script

```
SqlFile(@"Sql\UpdateTotalPrice.sql");
```

Just make sure you set 'Copy to output directory' to true on your .sql file.